# Finding HRESULT '-2146697191' Error message - clickonce setup error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, deployment, clickonce, hresult

I want to know what exactly HRESULT error means? This is occuring when user is trying to download clickonce application from our server. Hence to figure what is the problem behind it I want to know what does this HRESULT number refers to. I tried to use error lookup tool but it says message not found. Is there any way to find this error message? Also it would be great if anyone can tell me how to lookup for error message if HRESULT is given as decimal number?

For reference here is the error log in short:

```
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 5.1.3 {version}
Running checks for package '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1', phase BuildList
Reading value 'SP' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5'
Read integer value 1
Setting value '1 {int}' for property 'DotNet35SP'
The following properties have been set for package '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1':
Property: [DotNet35SP] = 1 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFx35setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'DotNet35SP' and value '1': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFx35setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://SomeWebSite.com/SomeApplication.application'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HRESULT -2146697191 (0x800C0019) means "The Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate is invalid." See [INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that is quite helpful to dig into the matter

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I was able to pinpoint the problem. In my case, the client's computer time was set to the year of 2011 (and it's 2018 now) so all certificates are not yet valid. Therefore, ClickOnce installer threw this exception. Fixed the time and problem gone. Ironically, this answer was posted in 2011 :D

Answer (score 3):

> Also it would be great if anyone can tell me how to lookup for error message if HRESULT is given as decimal number?

The way I do this is to enter the number into the calculator and then switch to hexadecimal display.

In this case it gives `FFFFFFFF800C0019`. Removing the leading `F`s gives an error code of `0x800C0019` which will be searchable.

Comment: Thanks for the info, yes I did that before posting it here, but in vain it says message not found. I directly used '-2146697191' in the tool and it converted that number to '0x800C0019' and said message not found. I got doubt on this process hence asked question about that too. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @JPReddy - I haven't had chance to lookup the error yet - does a Google search reveal anything.